# Error in dpkg when executing apt-get upgrade ( most of the commands )

Tags: ubuntu, dpkg, gdb

Typing `apt-get upgrade` returns the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing package gdb (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried a lot of solution, but still the error occurs. Please help me to get out from this problem.

Comment: what solutions did you tried? and what is the error, you forgot to paste it.

Comment: error : dpkg: error processing package gdb (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gdb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @BANJOSA this is error

Comment: sudo dpkg --configure -a this cmd also gives me the same error.

Comment: @Stephen Kitt - i try this command to uninstall the gdb sudo apt-get remove gdb 
but i got the same error.

Comment: problem solved, now i am able to get udgrade my packages. can you explain whats the problem with dpkg and gdb @StephenKitt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message gives some indication of what’s going on and how to fix it:

```
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
```

The problem is that the package state as described in `dpkg`’s “database” (the files under `/var/lib/dpkg/info` doesn’t match what’s on the system. This can happen because the files under `/var/lib/dpkg/info` got corrupted, or because the files installed by the package were changed without involving `dpkg`.

The appropriate fix is to reinstall `gdb`:

```
sudo apt --reinstall install gdb
```

This replaces the files on the system, including the `dpkg` database files, with the files in the package, if necessary downloading it again. As a result, the database ends up in sync with the file system again (at least, as far as `gdb`’s files are concerned).

Comment: Thanks @Stephen.